# Updating my Python code in order to speed everything up

Tags: python, multithreading, networkx

I have this function that I need to run to operate on a file:

```
def Creation(file):
    infile = open(file, "r")
    t=0
    gr=100000
    add_balance={}
    de_send={}
    de_rec={}
    count=0
    num_lines = int(sum(1 for line in open(file)))
    G=nx.DiGraph()
    GsimA=nx.DiGraph()
    in_deg={}
    out_deg={}
    line = infile.readline()
    while line:
        if count>=t+gr and count<t+gr+1: #copy of add_balance, de_send and de_rec
            bl=add_balance
            snd=de_send
            rec=de_rec
            in_deg={}
            out_deg={}
        if count>=t+gr and count<t+gr*2: #create a graph
            if count%2==0:
                inc=0
                fields=line.split(";")
                tr=int(fields[0].split(",")[1])
                G.add_node(-tr)
                GsimA.add_node(-tr)
                for ff in fields[1:]:
                    ffsplit=ff.split(",")
                    address=int(ffsplit[0])
                    amount=int(ffsplit[1])
                    G.add_node(address)
                    GsimA.add_node(address)
                    inc+=1
                    G.add_weighted_edges_from([(address,-tr,amount)])
                    if address not in add_balance.keys():
                        add_balance[address]=-amount
                    else:
                        add_balance[address]-=amount
                    if address not in de_send.keys():
                        de_send[address]=1
                    else:
                        de_send[address]+=1
                if inc in in_deg.keys():
                    in_deg[inc]+=1
                else:
                    in_deg[inc]=1
            else:
                outc=0
                fields=line.split(";")
                for ff in fields:
                        ffsplit=ff.split(",")
                        address=int(ffsplit[0])
                        amount=int(ffsplit[1])
                        G.add_node(address)
                        GsimA.add_node(address)
                        outc+=1
                        G.add_weighted_edges_from([(-tr,address,amount)])
                        if address not in add_balance.keys():
                            add_balance[address]=amount
                        else:
                            add_balance[address]+=amount
                        if address not in de_rec.keys():
                            de_rec[address]=1
                        else:
                            de_rec[address]+=1
                if outc in out_deg.keys():
                    out_deg[outc]+=1
                else:
                    out_deg[outc]=1    
            for i in G.nodes():
                if i>0:
                    if i in add_balance.keys():
                        G.nodes[i]["balance"]=add_balance[i]
                    else:
                        G.nodes[i]["balance"]=0
                    if i in bl.keys():
                        GsimA.nodes[i]["balance"]=bl[i]
                    else:
                        GsimA.nodes[i]["balance"]=0
                    if i in de_send.keys():
                        G.nodes[i]["in-degree"]=de_send[i]
                    else:
                        G.nodes[i]["in-degree"]=0
                    if i in snd.keys():
                        GsimA.nodes[i]["in-degree"]=snd[i] 
                    else:
                        GsimA.nodes[i]["in-degree"]=0
                    if i in de_rec.keys():
                        G.nodes[i]["out-degree"]=de_rec[i]
                    else:
                        G.nodes[i]["out-degree"]=0
                    if i in rec.keys():
                        GsimA.nodes[i]["out-degree"]=rec[i]
                    else:
                        GsimA.nodes[i]["out-degree"]=0
        if count==t+gr*2:
            GsimA=CreateTies(GsimA, in_deg, out_deg) #this function works properly so it's not the problem
            nx.write_gexf(G, "C:/Users/uccio/Desktop/tesi2/realgraph"+str(int(t/2))+"-"+str(int((t+gr)/2))+".gexf")
            nx.write_gexf(GsimA, "C:/Users/uccio/Desktop/tesi2/simAgraph"+str(int(t/2))+"-"+str(int((t+gr)/2))+".gexf")
            t+=100000
            G=nx.DiGraph()
            GsimA=nx.DiGraph()
        if count>=t+gr and count<t+gr*2 and count>=num_lines:
            GsimA=CreateTies(GsimA, in_deg, out_deg)
            nx.write_gexf(G, "C:/Users/uccio/Desktop/tesi2/realgraph"+str(int(t/2))+"-"+str(int((num_lines)/2))+".gexf")
            nx.write_gexf(GsimA, "C:/Users/uccio/Desktop/tesi2/simAgraph"+str(int(t/2))+"-"+str(int((num_lines)/2))+".gexf")
            break
        if count<t+gr: #pre graph creation
            if count%2==0:
                fields=line.split(";")
                tr=int(fields[0].split(",")[1])
                for ff in fields[1:]:
                    ffsplit=ff.split(",")
                    address=int(ffsplit[0])
                    amount=int(ffsplit[1])
                    if address not in add_balance.keys():
                        add_balance[address]=-amount
                    else:
                        add_balance[address]-=amount
                        
                    if address not in de_send.keys():
                        de_send[address]=1
                    else:
                        de_send[address]+=1
            else:
                fields=line.split(";")
                for ff in fields:
                    ffsplit=ff.split(",")
                    address=int(ffsplit[0])
                    amount=int(ffsplit[1])
                    if address not in add_balance.keys():
                        add_balance[address]=amount
                    else:
                        add_balance[address]+=amount
                    if address not in de_rec.keys():
                        de_rec[address]=1
                    else:
                        de_rec[address]+=1
        count+=1
        line=infile.readline()
    return ""
```

So, practically, the function read a file and for every line it updates 3 dictionaries (add_balance, de_send, de_rec) until it reach `t+gr` where it creates a networkx graph until `t+gr*2` where it saves the graph obtained (and a simulated one).
the file has almost 200 million lines made like this (between parenthesis what are called in the code):

```
1450863652,99602438(tr);86580762(address),16284(amount),98768263,401;86580762(address),24607(amount),99009389,1057;86580762(address),61080(amount),99445761,173 #0
109539809(address),100000(amount) #1
1450863652,99602439(tr);96679479(address),9804569(amount),98309470,2 #2
113221082(address),9704569(amount);113221083(address),99127(amount) #3
```

where the line 0 and 2 are the ones inside `if count%2` and the other ones in the `else`

My problem is that while it creates the graph (so in the `if count>=t+gr and count<t+gr*2:`) the code becomes a little bit slow (it takes about 10 second to do the first 100000 lines and 2/3 hours to do the following 100000)
Is there a way to speed up my code? I've read about using multiprocessing (in [here](https://superuser.com/questions/679679/how-to-increase-pythons-cpu-usage)) but I don't know how it can be applied in my code.

Comment: The fact it's slowing down suggests you're searching through things that are getting longer and longer.  I suspect things like `if x in d.keys()` is slow - it certainly is if `d.keys()` is treated as a list, but I'm not sure.  It's probably faster to do `if x in d`.

Comment: FYI - stackoverflow isn't really intended for answering questions of this form.  Read up on [mcve].

Comment: Worth being aware of an alternative:  `d[x] = d.get(x,0)+added_value` which will add `added_value` to `d[x]` and assign it to `d[x]` when `d[x]` exists but will use `0` when `d[x]` doesn't exist.  It doesn't use the nice `+=` or `-=` notation, but it avoids the if statements.

Comment: I didn't know about minimal reproducible example, i wil edit my question when I have a little bit of time. Thanks for the answer anyway!

Comment: You should profile your code to understand what is slowing down the execution, cProfile for instance.